# Virtualbox: Physical host doing routing between host-only networks appears to do NAT by default, which is not wanted

Tags: linux, virtualbox

**Configuration:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 host
- Virtualbox 4.3.18 (from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian )
- Ubuntu host functioning as a router - `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- Several host-only networks configured, traffic between these is routed by the host.

  - *vboxnet0:*

    - Prefix: 192.168.1.0/24
    - Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (this is the IP on the VM host)
  - *vboxnet1:*

    - Prefix: 192.168.2.0/24
    - Gateway: 192.168.2.1
  - and so on - there's more networks, but for the purposes of this question it's not relevant.

**Problem:**

When I make a connection from VM Alice in network vboxnet0 to VM Bob in network vboxnet1, on Bob the connection appears as if it was coming from the IP of the gateway. netstat or tcpdump on Bob would show the traffic that is coming from Alice as having a source IP of 192.168.2.1 (the gw IP), and not Alice's IP, which can be something like 192.168.1.30.

In other words, NAT appears to be happening. However, I don't want that - I just want my host/router to simply forward packets between subnets. Given that I didn't configure NAT explicitly, I am not sure why does it behave this way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is routed through the gateway, to be sure, but in normal circumstances, the source IP should not be replaced with the gw IP.

Comment: I guess I can put it in simple terms - my gw is doing NAT, but I don't want that. That's at the core of the problem.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: TBF I did not highlight the aspect of unwanted NAT in my original question. Edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a way do disable MASQUERADE in host-only networks.

If you really insist on having no masquerading, you can use a NAT network instead of a host-only network. In this case, the host acts as a router, by placing all VMs inside the same LAN, and allowing them to talk to each other without NATting. In this case, the host will NAT only outside communications.

Comment: The issue is that I need to put the VMs in multiple networks. I tried creating two NAT networks and placing a VM in each, but there's no connectivity from one VM to another. I think this works as intended.